# Clicking on the background of collapsible header collapses the content but main icon not changed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using collapsible contents from Bootstrap. So this is the actual visualization when I clicked on the background of collapsible-header.

[1st part ( not yet collapsed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAbAn.png)

[2nd part (After collapsed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSzPu.png)

As you noticed, the icon wasn't changed when I clicked on the collapsible-header background. The lists collapsed but I want the icon to be changed along by pressing the background afterwards.

However, there is no problem if i clicked on the icon itself and i will have the icon changed to plus sign and the contents will be collapsed as well.

But I would like to have my collapsible-header background to be responsive along with the icon as well. Please do help. Here's the sample code but I cant have proper visualization and I would like to apologize for the inconvenience.

```
     <div class="col-md-12" style="margin:20px 0 0 0">
          <ul class="collapsible collapsible-landing" data-collapsible="accordion">
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header">
                    <span class="pull-left"><h3>Categories</h3></span>
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a href="#catehide1" class="catehide2" id="catehide1"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href="#cateshow1" class="cateshow2" id="cateshow1"><i class="zmdi zmdi-minus"></i></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="collapsible-body">
                     <ul class="collapsible-list">
                        <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 1 </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 2 </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 3</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 4</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 5</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 6 </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="www.sample1.com">Sample 7</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="www.sample1.com">Sample 8 </a> </li>
                        <li class="clearfix"></li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>/
```

Heres the css part

```
.catehide2, .cateshow2 {
float: right;
font-size: 20px;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
padding:0;
}

.catehide2:hover, .cateshow2:hover {
 color: #9e9e9e;
 text-decoration: none;
 opacity: 1;
 }

.categorybox1 ul{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:none; 
height:auto;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight:450;
font-size:15px;
color:#424242;
border:0;
}

.categorybox1 ul li{
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 padding: 0 0 15px 40px;
 }

.categorybox1 ul li a:link, .categorybox1 ul li a:visited {
 color:#424242;
 text-decoration: none;
  }

 .categorybox1 ul li a:hover, .categorybox1 ul li a:active {
  color:#9e9e9e;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

  .collapsible-landing {
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  }

 .collapsible-landing .collapsible-header {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 padding: 0 24px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: none;
 }

.collapsible-landing .collapsible-header h3 {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 500;
 padding:0;margin: 0;
 line-height: 60px;
 }
 .collapsible-landing .collapsible-header i {
  width: auto;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0;
   }

 .collapsible-landing .collapsible-body {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
 .collapsible-list li a {
  width:25%;
  padding:10px 24px;
  float:left;
  color:#424242;
   }
  .collapsible-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  color:#9e9e9e;
  }
  .collapsible-list li.clearfix {
   clear:both;
   padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**Pure CSS Way**

Problem of icon change on expand and collapse of accordion has been resolved.

Check example code at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/BLyWRK?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 " style="margin:20px 0 0 0">
  <ul class="collapsible collapsible-landing">
    <li>
      <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test">
        <h3 class="panel-title accordion-toggle">Categories</h3>

      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body collapsible-body panel-collapse collapse" id="test">
        <ul class="collapsible-list">
          <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 1 </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 2 </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 3</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 4</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 5</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="www.sample1.com"> Sample 6 </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="www.sample1.com">Sample 7</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="www.sample1.com">Sample 8 </a> </li>
          <li class="clearfix"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 450;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #424242;
  border: 0;
}

.collapsible-landing {
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.collapsible-list {
  background: #efefef;
}

.collapsible-list li a {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  float: left;
  color: #424242;
}

.collapsible-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

.collapsible-list li.clearfix {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.accordion-toggle:after {
  /* symbol for "opening" panels */      
  font-family: 'Material-Design-Iconic-Font';
  content: "\f273";
  float: right;
  color: inherit;
}

.panel-heading.collapsed .accordion-toggle:after {
  /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
  content: "\f278";
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping, but is the icon changed to something else?  It is required for the plus and minus sign to be there.. I could only check this code tomorrow as I left it in my workplace

Comment: You are using the [zavoloklom](http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/cheatsheet.html) icons. I have updated my code in answer. Just include the zmdi css in your HTML. For implementation of zmdi icons you can go to the mentioned link. I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of css while a small jquery function just solve your problem easily.
Hoping it will help you!

```js
$(function(){
  $('#collapse1').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Show');
  })
  $('#collapse1').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> Hide');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible Panel</h2>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a id="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> show
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry but this is not the ideal panel I wanted.. Thanks for  helping though. Cheers.